# Accessing UIVisualEffectView from completion block crashes with the EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uivisualeffectview

I am applying a blur effect to `UIImageView` using `UIVisualEffectView`.

When I try to access the `UIVisualEffectView` from the completion block, I get the crash `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

I've also tried to put the code in Main Thread but nothing happens good with that

Here's my code

```
func addBlurEffectView(frame: CGRect, value: CGFloat) {
    if value != 0 {
        if let sub = self.subviews.compactMap({ $0 as? UIVisualEffectView }).first {
            print("Blur effect view exists")
            sub.frame = self.bounds
            self.blurEffect.setValue(value/10, forKeyPath: "blurRadius")
            sub.effect = self.blurEffect
        } else {
            print("Blur effect view doesn't exist")
            self.blurEffect = (NSClassFromString("_UICustomBlurEffect") as! UIBlurEffect.Type).init()
            let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(frame: /*UIScreen.main.bounds*/frame)
            self.blurEffect.setValue(value/10, forKeyPath: "blurRadius")
            blurView.effect = self.blurEffect
            blurView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
            self.addSubview(blurView)
        }
    } else {
        if let sub = self.subviews.compactMap({ $0 as? UIVisualEffectView }).first {
            sub.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

Here, in the above code, the **blurEffect** is the global variable, i.e.,

```
var blurEffect = (NSClassFromString("_UICustomBlurEffect") as! UIBlurEffect.Type).init()
```

**Note:** I am using this code also with slider's valueChanged event, everything works perfectly with that, but the problem arises only when I access the function from completion block

I get the crash at the below line

**sub.frame = self.bounds**

I have no idea how to solve this issue

Thanks!!

Comment: Why are you using this approach?  Why don't you set up the effect view in the usual way - e.g. https://www.raywenderlich.com/167-uivisualeffectview-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for the response! Answer to your question is, I want to increase and decrease the blur effect value as slider changes, this is the reason why am I not using it in a usual way